# Performing multiple substring replacements on a string

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have code like the following, which performs a series of replacements on a string, to convert it to its final form.

```
public String convertString(String string) {

String convertedString = string;

if( string.contains("something")) {
    convertedString = convertStringA(string);

    return convertedString;
} else if (string.contains("something else")) {
    convertedString = convertStringB(string);

    return convertedString;
} ...

// many more else if blocks

else if (string.contains("something else")) {
    convertedString = convertStringXXX(string);

    return convertedString;
} ...

}
```

How can I do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with an interface:

```
public interface Converter {
    boolean canHandle(String inputString);
    String convert(String inputString);
}
```

and write a few implementations, like `SomethingConverter`, `OtherConverter`, etc. An example:

```
public class SomethingConverter implements Converter {

    public boolean canHandle(final String inputString) {
        return StringUtils.contains(inputString, "something");
    }

    public String convert(String inputString) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then put them into a collection:

```
final List<Converter> converters = new ArrayList<>();
converters.put(new SomethingCoverter());
converters.put(new OtherConverter());
```

and finally use them:

```
for (final Converter converter: converters) {
    if (converter.canHandle(inputString)) {
        return converter.convert(inputString);
    }    
}
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled input: " + inputString); // may not be applicable, depends on the requirements
```

I've used [`StringUtils.contains`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) beacuse it's null-safe, it does not throw NullPointerException if the `inputString` is `null`

(The code is not tested, feel free to fix the typos if there is any.)

Comment: Thanks! It looks much better! I will use your solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your Algorithm is a little bit too abstract to provide a one size fits all solution.

What does it mean, when a string contains "something" or "something else"?
Are they completely different strings like "I know (something)" and "He gave me (something else)"? Or are there similarities like:
"Peter knows (something)" and "Joe knows (something else)". So "knows" would be the keyword after which your phrase occurs. "Contains" is somehow a little bit unprecise.

If it is relativly easy to extract the substring you need -perhaps with a regular expression- you could use a HashMap to provide the correct converter with a simple call with the phrase as the key.

```
public class Converters {

  HashMap<String, Converter> converters=new HashMap<String, Converter>();    

  public Converters(){
      // Fill Hashmap here
  }

  public Converter getConverterFor(String phrase){
      if (!converters.containsKey(phrase)) throw new NoConverterFoundException();
      return converters(phrase);
  }    

}
```

Converter is here an interface, which all of your converters have to implement.
This solution provides easy maintenance - a new Converter needs only one new entry in the HashMap. And no unreadable if-else-whattheeckyouwantelse-blocks anymore.

But this is only one possible solution. A better solution requires more information on your phrases.

Comment: Strings are completely different.